# WSO2 not honoring XSD

Tags: php, soap, xsd, wso2

After spending a few hours with it, I'm getting close to a point where I might actually start using WSO for SOAP services, but I've run into one disturbing aspect.

First off the service code

```
class Order
{
    /** 
     * @var string
     */
    public $item_name;

    /** 
     * @var nonNegativeInteger
     */
    public $amount;

    public function calcPrice()
    {   
        return (float)($this->amount * 5); 
    }   
}

/**
 * Service function getPrice
 *
 * @param object Order $Order
 * @return double $price
 */
function getPrice(Order $Order)
{
    return $Order->calcPrice();
}

// create service in WSDL mode
$service = new WSService(
        array(
            'bindingStyle' => 'rpc',
            'opParams' => array('getPrice' => 'MIXED'),

            // define the actions => operations map
            "actions" => array(
                "http://wsf.local/wsdl_generation/hacked_service.php/getPrice"
                    => "getPrice"),

            // define the class map
            "classmap" => array("Order" => "Order"),

            // define the operations map
            "operations" => array("getPrice" => "getPrice")));

// process client requests and reply 
$service->reply();
```

Great how I can type hint the Order class!  Let's take a peak at the WSDL; the WSDL is being generated w/ the `service_name.php?wsdl` approach, so WSO is generating it off the service code above.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Order">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item_name" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now look, even more good news; we've got some tight requirements on the values allowed for Order objects through the service.

So when I finally take this and head to SoapUI to test, passing something arbitrary for `item_name` & a number like 5 for `amount`, out comes the value 25, awesome.  When I try to pass something invalid for amount EG NOT a nonNegativeInteger, WSO casts to an integer and the call to getPrice receives 0 for the value of amount!

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that the point of the XSD, to prevent invalid values from making it into the service code?  I could test the value inside the function, but then what's the point of using XSDs at all here?  Is there a way to configure WSO to send an error response for requests when SimpleTypes don't validate?

Comment: @note experimented w/ `SoapServer` and able to get the desired effect, however unable to get validation against required attributes to work.

Comment: I've since found out there are a number of features not implemented by SoapServer https://gist.github.com/1539513, but was expecting more from WSO2; shocked it can't even handle the most trivial example!